# Decode QR Code obtained from server within application

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, server

My application downloads QR code from server and once its in the application I would like to decode it.I am using a image view to display it.I have used zxing library but it scans something displayed on other device not on same device.Please let me know if anyone has any idea about how to go on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, zxing is at heart just a simple Java library which you can embed in any Java-based application. You just want the core library (https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/core) and can see some sample code in https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/javase/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/j2se

Answer (score 0):

Hi I finally found the answer at the following.I pulled the code from the server and converted it into bitmap and then the bitmap can be converted to binary bitmap and decoded.
http://nizaqatali.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/android-qr-code-reader/